# Convert odd time format to hours

Tags: python, r, date, datetime

[image]

Hello, what's the easiest way to reformat a date that looks like "2017-01-01T19:33:28+0000"

For example, that date means January 1st, 2017, at 7:33:28pm.

I'm interested in **removing** the month, day, and year, and **keeping** hour and minutes only.

In the data I'm looking at, users' software commands take place all on the same day, over 2 hours (7pm to 9pm). (See image)

**I'd like to reformat the time to easily analyze command distribution over these two hours.**

Suggestions for either Python or r? Maybe for making time intervals?

**Update** I want to use the posted solution below

> from datetime import datetime
>
> x = datetime.strptime('2017-01-01T19:33:28+0000',
>   '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')\
>               .strftime('%H:%M')

However I can only do this for one value in a column. How do you apply it to all values in an entire column?

[Column values to convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1uKg.png)

Thanks!

Comment: did you try code or solution? did you get an error? did you search before you ask?

Comment: BTW: in R, you have either a `Date` or `POSIXt` object that includes date and time. There is no object for time-only. If you need just the time-of-day, I suggest you parse out the numbers and convert to a `numeric` of hours or days.

Comment: @r2evans just because it's a byproduct of parsing, doesn't mean you have to use it.

Comment: I don't disagree. All I was getting at (poorly?) is that there is a clear concept of *date* and *datetime* but no *time*. So there's no automatic function to create said non-existent object, it's all user code. And parsing/extraction is straight forward with `as.POSIXct(...,format="...")` and `format(...,format="%H")`.

Comment: Yes I got errors, yes I searched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Python solution using `datetime`, which belongs in the standard library:

```
from datetime import datetime

x = datetime.strptime('2017-01-01T19:33:28+0000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')\
            .strftime('%H:%M')

# '19:33'
```

Comment: this worked, thank you

now I'm trying to figure out how to run this for a column. it says it can't be run on a series

I'm a beginner if you can't tell!

Comment: Can anyone help this be run for a column?

Comment: That a new question. You can accept an answer to this question and ask a new one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dateutil`:

```
import dateutil
t = dateutil.parse("2017-01-01T19:33:28+0000")
t.hour # prints 19
t.minute # prints 33
```

You can decide what you want to do with the hours and minutes later.

**EDIT**: By the way, this is in python.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I got this error

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-c1d3df4dc54b> in <module>()
----> 1 t_test = dateutil.parse("2017-01-01T19:33:28+0000")

AttributeError: module 'dateutil' has no attribute 'parse'

Answer (score 1):

In R the `lubridate` package has a lot of options for this ([doc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf)).

```
library(lubridate)
t <- as_datetime("2017-01-01T19:33:28+0000")
hour(t)
#[1] 19
minute(t)
#[1] 33
```

You'll likely be particularly interested in the `interval` function.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite as feature rich as `dateutil` but vectorized: `numpy`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> example
['2018-01-01T12:00:00+0000', '2018-01-01T16:37:45+0000', '2018-01-01T21:15:30+0000', '2018-01-02T01:53:15+0000', '2018-01-02T06:31:00+0000', '2018-01-02T11:08:45+0000']
>>>
# create numpy array, 'M8' stands for datetime64
>>> A = np.array(example, dtype='M8')
>>> A
array(['2018-01-01T12:00:00', '2018-01-01T16:37:45',
       '2018-01-01T21:15:30', '2018-01-02T01:53:15',
       '2018-01-02T06:31:00', '2018-01-02T11:08:45'],
      dtype='datetime64[s]')
>>> 
# we have to manually extract hours and minutes but it is easy:
# convert to units 'h' (hour, discarding minutes and seconds) and 
# 'D' (day, also discarding smaller units) and take the difference
>>> hours = A.astype('M8[h]') - A.astype('M8[D]')
# and similar for minutes
>>> minutes = A.astype('M8[m]') - A.astype('M8[h]')
>>> hours
array([12, 16, 21,  1,  6, 11], dtype='timedelta64[h]')
>>> minutes
array([ 0, 37, 15, 53, 31,  8], dtype='timedelta64[m]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another lubridate solution (for R):

```
library(lubridate)
t<-ymd_hms("2017-01-01T19:33:28+0000")
hour(t)
#[1] 19
minute(t)
#[1] 33
```

Comment: Please stop (incorrectly) capitalizing the names of R packages .

Comment: I fixed it.  Thanks.  There are many packages that have capitals.  Where have you seen a convention?

Comment: The convention is to use the correct spelling and surround them with some sort of quotes. I generally use a format like `name`-package (where the "name"-item is flanked by backticks so that it gets displayed as code by the SO formatting features.)  To do otherwise is to lure newbies, especially immigrants from SAS, into flagrant capitalization. R is not SAS and capitalization conventions are not the same. R functions are not PROCs.

Answer (score 0):

The no-added-packages approach in R would be:

```
as.POSIXct( "2017-01-01T19:33:28+0000", format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", tz="UTC" )
[1] "2017-01-01 19:33:28 UTC"
```